# Converting scraped HTML table to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with converting html table to pandas dataframe. I have used `BeautifulSoup` for **scraping**, and now I want to convert that table to pandas dataframe with `read_html` function.
But for some reason I get an error.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_World_Golf_Ranking', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


html_table = soup.find_all("table")[0]
print(html_table)
print(type(html_table))


df = pd.read_html(html_table)
print(df[0])
```

The error that I get is:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

But `html_table` is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are passing bs4 object to pandas, you should pass an html string.

Update the line with following code:

```
df = pd.read_html(str(html_table))
```

This should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Simplify that even more as pandas' `read_html()` can take in the url

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_World_Golf_Ranking'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```